# Return MySQL error from CFQUERY statement

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

Stupid problem, I have a function that runs a query several times in a  block & reports/emails if/when a query fails. I'm wondering if/how I can capture the actual MySQL error & return it as part of my email/report.

So far I see no way to do this.

Any thoughts?

-thanks
-sean

UPDATE

Thanks Charlie;

I never considered using the cfcatch structure [and truthfully didn't realize it returned so much useful stuff!!]

Unfortunately the host does not allow cfdump so I had to go about it like this:

```
<cftry>

    <some sql>

<cfcatch type="any">

    <cfscript>
        for (key in cfcatch) {
            try{
                variables.report = variables.report&"<li>"&key&"="&cfcatch[key]&"</li>";
            }
            catch(Any excpt) {
                variables.report = variables.report&"<li>"&key&"=??</li>";
            }
        }
    </cfscript>

<cfcatch>

<cftry>
```

Comment: Hey Sean:  Your solution is fine.  You don't actually need the dump... I was just using it to show you what information was available.  You can get at the information however you need to (which is what you've done) :)

Comment: @charlie - thanks Charlie, you provided the clue I needed ;) [it does work well btw]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the native database error returned as part of the cfcatch?

```
<cftry>
    (some sql here)
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" />
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

If you run that on a page, and intentionally use some invalid SQL, what do you see in the cfdump?